# Need that Partner User see contacts that match certain field with their own contact

Tags: community, permissions, partner-communities, sharing-sets

Partner user should only see contact records that are related to them based on a field on the contact record, let's say Account for example.

What I have tried:

- Sharing Settings: Contact | Public Read Only | Public Read Only.

Reason: there's a self-registration site (lightning component available from external). This has a field for related contact, and if I set this sharing setting as private I will not be able to do this lookup.

- Sharing set inside community settings:

Contact.Account = Contact:Faculty__c.Account

I have touched Permission Set and Profiles but nothing in there to accomplish this.

Still can't find the right way to do this, any suggestions, please.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Account sharing configured correctly for the Accounts and all the Contacts belong to the relevant Accounts, you should be able to configure Contacts as Controlled by Parent, and Users with access to the parent Account should then have access to the Contacts.

You may also consider using Account teams if you have not got the correct Account accesses set up on the Partner Users. This can be automated through code to automatically provide access to a given Partner User based on an Account in a lookup field on their Contact record.